Oracle SQL Developer Web - Navigator objects not loading
Installed Oracle-Apex/ Oracle-ORDS on Windows 10 and all working fine apart from some weird issue when accessing SQL Navigator page where the object panel will not load (just get busy hr glass). The same happens when viewing the Data Modelling page as well. I can access tables via queries etc no problem and used various browsers but same problem. I've created new users / restarted ORDS but no joy. Any idea what's causing this? Thanks

It's a bug, will be sorted in next ORDS drop. I think if you grant RESOURCE to your user that should get you going in meantime.

Aha thank you very much - will try your suggestion

Just to add that did work so thanks again
